# Exporting content translation to similar server

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n, migrations, importing-exporting

I have 2 instances of the same site built using Drupal. Both need to be translated, and most of the work of the translation has been done on site A and we need to take the translations from site A to site B. Site B will have slightly newer content, but not a lot and a new version of Drupal (both sites are/will be 8.6+).

I can export translation but they're just for the interface, the content is not getting exported. Is there a way to export or send the translations in site A to site B without having to translate everything again one by one in site B?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into various modules that support content migration, like https://www.drupal.org/project/content_export_yaml, https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync, https://www.drupal.org/project/cms_content_sync? You could probably set up a permanent automatic "refresh" procedure with Feeds or Migrate modules.

Comment: I've seen quite a few modules but most of them don't mention what happens to the translations... Most of the content is already in Site B I just need to send the translations.

Comment: Translations are content, they're not even different nodes in D8 like they were in D7, so why not try them out and report back?